# Navigator 2.0 with Pageview

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm playing around with the new Flutter Navigator 2.0 and facing an issue with PageView implementation.

The children of the PageView are not pushed automatically into the pages stack so I have to do it by myself. That leads to the fact that the children of the PageView have not BottomNavigationBar.

Sample Code

```
void mountHome() {
    delegate.addPage(HomePageConfig);
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => mountHome());
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        children: [Home(), Create(), Chat(), Settings()],
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(.....)
    );
  }
```

Anybody facing this issue or having a solution?

Comment: I'm also curious about implementing navigator 2.0 with CupertinoTabBar, were you able to do it?

Comment: I used the flutter package route master at the end to do it.